# Verify if Insertion query was completed in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

So say I did something like this:

```
Employee emp=new Employee();
emp.setId(1); // PK
emp.setName("Earl");
emp.setAge("73");

session.save();
```

According to the tutorial here: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/ , this should bring about an insert in the Employee table, assuming all mappings are correct. However, I keep on getting a serialization error. Is it because I am giving the ID a value? The query generates (However it takes Id as NULL... why is this?)

Is there any way I can verify barring checking the database to see if the query was done? Also, please do look at my other queries. I am very new to hibernate.

Comment: That is a very old Hibernate tutorial, you should look at something newer. Anyway, can you post the stack trace and hibernate mapping file or annotated Employee class.

Comment: may be you have auto generated id.. and i think you should wrap in a transaction to do commit and rollback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by keeping your id as generated value and you can type cast the return type to integer.In model class place this annotation upon id

```
@generatedvalue(strategy = generationtype.auto)
private int id;
```

Then there no need to insert the Employee id hibernate automatically generates the value and inserts and to check that values are inserted

```
Int i=(Integer)session.save(emp);
if(i > 0)
{
System.out.println("Values inserted");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all check that you pass a value to the function session.save():

```
session.save(emp);
```

If it still fails...

May be your primary key is set to auto increment. So you need not to specify a value for it.
Also try wrapping it in a transaction.
Just try this :

```
Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction();
Employee emp=new Employee();
//emp.setId(1); // PK
emp.setName("Earl");
emp.setAge("73");

session.save(emp);
txn.commit();
```

And best wishes..